# lm finding predicted values of a factor from a dataset that has been split

Tags: r, lm, predict

I have split a data set from the Column WithSTV, which is discrete, into two datasets. From there a run the lm for each dataset and again from there I need the predicted probabilities of a single discrete variable in these models.  I must then plot this.  I am getting the exact value for each which makes no sense.  Please find the code and data below.

I have tried multiple packages and avenues including ggplot2, DAMisc, etc.

```
    library(readstata13)
    library(haven)
    library(sjlabelled) 
    library(sjmisc)
    library(sjstats)
    library(ggeffects) 
    library(sjPlot)
    dat <- read.dta13("STV.dta")
    dat <- na.omit(dat)
    zig<-split(dat, dat$WithSTV) ##split dataframe by WithSTV    variable

   ##this == WithSTV=0
    zig5<- zig[[1]] ##sperate by 1st level
    blah55 <-lm(PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested +    nonpartisan + presidential_election + education_level, data=zig5) 
      summary(blah55)
```

---

```
      ##this == WithSTV=1
     zig10<- zig[[2]] ##sperate by 2nd level

     blah10 <-lm(PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + nonpartisan + presidential_election + education_level, data=zig10)
    summary(blah10)
```

---

```
    ##WithSTV==0
    d<-zig5
    d$nonpartisan <- as.factor(d$nonpartisan)
    fit<-lm(PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + nonpartisan +    presidential_election + education_level, data=d)
    d$predicted <- predict(fit)   # Save the predicted values
    d$residuals <- residuals(fit)

     plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("nonpartisan"))

     ##WithSTV==1
     d<-zig10
     d$nonpartisan <- as.factor(d$nonpartisan)
     fit2<-lm(PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + nonpartisan  + presidential_election + education_level, data=d)
     d$predicted <- predict(fit2)   # Save the predicted values
     d$residuals <- residuals(fit2)

     plot_model(fit2, type = "pred", terms = c("nonpartisan"))
```

This is a link to the data. This is not a large file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HBssOfb0QX6BTh6ipwlJCRf3ZOT5zKmE/view?usp=sharing

I am expecting the predicted values of nonpartisan for each model to not be identical or close to identical but more stacked/ stairs looking. So, for example, if I compare nonpartisan for zig5/ fit and zig10/fit they will say around 3 & 5 not both 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So from not knowing your exact research question, I would include the WithSTV as a predictor in the model and not try to model them separately. I imagine that the intervention was on the entire sample so you're interested in the marginal difference between those exposed and those who were not exposed. If that is the case, leaving WithSTV in a single linear model is a good approach.

Here is the approach with that in mind that you use:

```
library(haven)
library(tidyverse)

# Read in the Data
dat <- haven::read_dta("STV.dta")

# Fit the Model including WithSTV as a fixed effect
blah10 <-lm(PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + 
              nonpartisan + presidential_election + 
              education_level + WithSTV, data=dat)

# Inspect the Coefficients
# install.packages("arm") # great utility package
arm::coefplot(blah10)

arm::display(blah10)

# Add the prediction intervals
marginal_combos <- model.matrix(PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + 
                                  nonpartisan + presidential_election + 
                                  education_level + WithSTV,
                                data = dat)
# Add the Predicted Values to Original Data with Pred Interval
dat_fitted <- dat %>% 
  bind_cols(pred = predict(blah10, newdata = .,  interval="predict") %>% 
              as_tibble())

# Generate the Marginal Graph
# This basically will make the fitted lines and then the prediction intervals in gray
dat_fitted %>% 
  mutate(nonpartisan = as_factor(nonpartisan)) %>% 
  mutate(WithSTV = as_factor(WithSTV)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(nonpartisan, fit, group = WithSTV))+
  geom_line(aes(color = WithSTV))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = .1)
```

[image: graph of marginals]
This shows that the estimates are slightly different for those with and without for the point estimates, but that the prediction intervals are contained. So there isn't a huge, distinct, difference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought I responded to this earlier.  There are some diagnostic issues with the model how I have it as well as how it is specified here.  I am considering other options like gaussian glm/ log, etc.  It could very well be this is just the way it is.

Comment: Yeah with this model I would check out the lme4 package or brms and use hierarchical linear models with some of the demographic features as random effects.

Comment: tried that and even ran it in rstanarm-- says the model is overly complex. still working through it.

Comment: @Афанасия Геннадьевна interesting..maybe you could put stronger priors? As I remember the data set you have isn't very large (low number of observations per group) e.g. N(0,0.01) for some of the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, the differences between the two subsets of your data indeed seem to be rather small. This is true both for predicted values, adjusted by the covariates of your models, as well as the raw mean values of your outcome for each subgroup (see results at the very bottom).

If you would expect more differences, there might be an issue with your data (preparation)?

```r
library(sjlabelled)
library(ggeffects)
library(sjPlot)
library(dplyr)

d <- read_stata("D:/Downloads/STV.dta")
dat <- na.omit(d)
zig <- split(dat, dat$WithSTV)

zig5 <- zig[[1]]
zig5$nonpartisan <- as.factor(zig5$nonpartisan)
fit <- lm(
  PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + nonpartisan + presidential_election + education_level,
  data = zig5
)

zig10 <- zig[[2]]
zig10$nonpartisan <- as.factor(zig10$nonpartisan)
fit2 <- lm(
  PercentRunoff1  ~ Statewide + Contested + nonpartisan + presidential_election + education_level,
  data = zig10
)

ggpredict(fit, "nonpartisan")
#> 
#> # Predicted values of PercentRunoff1
#> # x = nonpartisan
#> 
#>  x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
#>  0     0.095     0.003    0.090     0.100
#>  1     0.198     0.007    0.184     0.212
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> *             Statewide =  0.05
#> *             Contested =  0.70
#> * presidential_election =  0.52
#> *       education_level = 82.71

ggpredict(fit2, "nonpartisan")
#> 
#> # Predicted values of PercentRunoff1
#> # x = nonpartisan
#> 
#>  x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
#>  0     0.099     0.004    0.092     0.107
#>  1     0.268     0.007    0.255     0.282
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> *             Statewide =  0.05
#> *             Contested =  0.77
#> * presidential_election =  0.43
#> *       education_level = 82.56


dat %>% 
  group_by(WithSTV, nonpartisan) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(PercentRunoff1))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   WithSTV [2]
#>   WithSTV nonpartisan  mean
#>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       0           0 0.101
#> 2       0           1 0.165
#> 3       1           0 0.114
#> 4       1           1 0.223
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: See other answer for my reply.  adding-- yes it is possible this is just how it is.  I am trying to exhaust all options to be sure.